# R remove header line after placing Kable side by side in Rmarkdown generated HTML

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I'm using `Rmarkdown` to generate an HTML output, where two `kables` are placed side by side using `kable::kables`. However, there's an extra line above the side-by-side kables that I would like to remove. I've read the [documentation of kableExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html), but seems like they didn't cover this issue.

The horizontal line that I would like to remove is indicated by the red arrow below.

[image: output_HTML_with_kable_extra_line]

Here's my `Rmarkdown` code for your reference:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "benson23"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: default
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    toc_float: true
    code_folding: hide
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(rmarkdown)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
```

## Help with Kable

As you can see, there's an extra line above the aligned tables, which I would like to remove.

```{r kable_extra_line}
df1 <- tibble(Dummy = c(90748, 91006, 90748, 91006), 
                       A = c(0, 6, 1, 110), 
                       B = c(8, 0, 339, 0), 
                       C = c(6, 7, 909, 309), 
                       D = c(0, 0, 0, 0))

df2 <- tibble(Dummy = c(90748, 91006, 90748, 91006), 
                       A = c(0, 901, 0, 50), 
                       B = c(0, 1, 122, 0), 
                       C = c(1847, 1, 754, 625), 
                       D = c(1, 0, 0, 0))
kables(list(
  kable(df1) %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "bordered"),
                  full_width = F) %>%
    row_spec(0, bold = T) %>%
    pack_rows("Pack some rows here", 1, 2, 
              label_row_css = "background-color: #666; color: #fff;") %>%
    pack_rows("Pack some rows here", 3, 4, 
              label_row_css = "background-color: #666; color: #fff;"),
  kable(df2) %>% 
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "bordered"),
                  full_width = F) %>%
    row_spec(0, bold = T) %>%
    pack_rows("Pack some rows here", 1, 2, 
              label_row_css = "background-color: #666; color: #fff;") %>%
    pack_rows("Pack some rows here", 3, 4, 
              label_row_css = "background-color: #666; color: #fff;")
)) %>% 
  kable_styling() 
```
````

It'd be great if you have any idea on how to remove the line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the css `.kable_wrapper { border: hidden;}`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "benson23"
output:
  html_document:
  theme: default
toc: yes
toc_depth: 4
toc_float: true
code_folding: hide
---
  
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(rmarkdown)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
```

<style>
.kable_wrapper {
  border: hidden;
}
</style>

## Help with Kable

As you can see, there's an extra line above the aligned tables, which I would like to remove.

```{r kable_extra_line}
    df1 <- tibble(Dummy = c(90748, 91006, 90748, 91006), 
                           A = c(0, 6, 1, 110), 
                           B = c(8, 0, 339, 0), 
                           C = c(6, 7, 909, 309), 
                           D = c(0, 0, 0, 0))

    df2 <- tibble(Dummy = c(90748, 91006, 90748, 91006), 
                           A = c(0, 901, 0, 50), 
                           B = c(0, 1, 122, 0), 
                           C = c(1847, 1, 754, 625), 
                           D = c(1, 0, 0, 0))
    kables(list(
      kable(df1) %>%
        kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "bordered"),
                      full_width = F) %>%
        row_spec(0, bold = T) %>%
        pack_rows("Pack some rows here", 1, 2, 
                  label_row_css = "background-color: #666; color: #fff;") %>%
        pack_rows("Pack some rows here", 3, 4, 
                  label_row_css = "background-color: #666; color: #fff;"),
      kable(df2) %>% 
        kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "bordered"),
                      full_width = F) %>%
        row_spec(0, bold = T) %>%
        pack_rows("Pack some rows here", 1, 2, 
                  label_row_css = "background-color: #666; color: #fff;") %>%
        pack_rows("Pack some rows here", 3, 4, 
                  label_row_css = "background-color: #666; color: #fff;")
    )) %>% 
      kable_styling() 
```
````

Comment: Brilliant! But how do you know the css class for all these `Rmarkdown` generated stuff?

Comment: In Chrome or Firefox: Right click on the table or sth elese -> Inspect